# How can I remove rows of a previous search in my dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my JSF application I have a dataTable that displays rows according to the button selected [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NE7h.png).

Each button displays different rows. The problem is that when I click another button, the new rows appear at the bottom of the dataTable but the old rows are still there. How can I empty the dataTable, so it only displays the rows corresponding to the button that is clicked? 
This is my **view**:

```
<h:panelGrid id="png3" columns="1" style="font-size: 11px; text-height: font-size; text-align: left; font-weight: bold">
<h:panelGrid id="png31" columns="2">
    <p:panel id="pnlCab" header="Cabecera">
        <p:dataTable id="dataCabecera" value="#{cargaHorariaController.listaActivDoc}" var="listaActDoc" 
                     rowKey="#{listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactPK.pzptcabperjactActividad}" selectionMode="single" 
                     selection="#{cargaHorariaController.listaActivSelected}">
            <p:column headerText="Actividad" style="width: 55%">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactPK.pzptcabperjactActividad} - #{cargaHorariaController.descActiv(listaActDoc.pzptcabperjactPK.pzptcabperjactActividad)}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="" style="width: 45%">
                <div align="center">
                    <p:commandButton value="Ver actividad" id="cmdSubacti" process="dataCabecera" 
                                     action="#{cargaHorariaController.consultarSubactividadesDoc()}" 
                                     update=":formPrincipal:pnlDet">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{listaActDoc}" target="#{cargaHorariaController.activSelected}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel id="pnlDet" header="Detalle">
        <p:dataTable id="dataDetalle" value="#{cargaHorariaController.listaSubactividad}" var="listaSubact"
                     rowKey="#{listaSubact.subactividad}" selectionMode="single" 
                     selection="#{cargaHorariaController.listaSubactivSelected}">
            <p:column headerText="Subactividad" style="width: 35%">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{listaSubact.subactividad} - #{cargaHorariaController.descSubacti(listaSubact.subactividad)}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Horas" style="width: 15%">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{listaSubact.horas}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="" style="width: 50%">
                <div align="center">
                    <p:commandButton value="Actualizar" type="button" id="actiActu" onclick="PF('wdlgSubactiAct').show()" />
                    <p:spacer width="70px" height="0px"> </p:spacer>
                    <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" id="subactiEli" process="dataDetalle" 
                                     onclick="PF('wdlgEliSub').show()">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{listaSubact}" 
                                                     target="#{cargaHorariaController.subactivSelected}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And this is my **bean**:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class CargaHorariaController  extends ControllerBase implements Serializable 
{
    @EJB
    private PzptcabperjactFacade pf;
    @EJB
    private PerjactFacade perjactFacade;

    public void consultarSubactividadesDoc()
    {
        listaSubactiDoc = pf.findSubactiDoc(activSelected.getPzptcabperjactPK().getPzptcabperjactActividad(), pidmSelected, periodoSelected);
        for(Iterator i = listaSubactiDoc.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
        {
            subactividadDto crn = new subactividadDto();
            Object[] values = (Object[]) i.next();

            crn.setActividad(values[0].toString());
            crn.setSubactividad(values[1].toString());
            crn.setCodperiodo(values[2].toString());
            crn.setPidm(values[3].toString());
            crn.setFechaActividad(values[4].toString());                
            crn.setFechaInicio(values[5].toString());
            crn.setFechaFin(values[6].toString());
            crn.setHoras(values[7].toString());

            lstCrn.add(crn);       
        }
        listaSubactividad = lstCrn;
    }
}
```

I've tried setting the **listaSubactividad** list to null at the beginning of the **consultarSubactividadesDoc()** method, but I got the same result. I changed the @SessionScoped annotation to @ViewScoped with no luck. I also used listaSubactividad.clear() getting a NullPointerException in the process. What can I do?

Comment: The answer really is to clean your list... Find out why that is not happening

Comment: Debug your code... You said you tried to clean `listaSubactividad` but did you clean the list you assign to it and where you add items to? Please...

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, I, did... nothing happens. I read a post and it talks about clearing the EntityManager, because it must be saving entities from the last invokation... etc. How can I do it?

Comment: I think that you are having a NullPointerException after a clear() because you are using an iterator on that list. I can give you guide lines to do what you want. Suppose you have a **list** that is used to display data in a datatable, if you want to remove all the rows of the datatable and display new rows do this: in the method that does that (for example search()) you can put **list** =your new content, and add update="idTable" in the commandButton that starts that method.